# Xcode running into C++ Pointer Errors

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, this

so I'm working on this code and I get an error "invalid operands to binary expression 'int' to 'int *'" I'll show you the test method I tried which worked and what I'm trying to get to work which is giving me an error.

```
//assume aptr has been declared in a base class
template<class T>
void SortableVector<T>::sortDescending() {    
    for(int x = 0; x < this->arraySize; x++)
        cout << *(this->aptr + x) << ' '; // this line works just fine. 
    //everything beyond this line does not work
    for ( int i = 0; i < this->arraySize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < this->arraySize; j++)
        {
            if ( *(this->aptr + i) < *(this->aptr + j))
            {
                int temporary = *(this->aptr+i);
                *(this->aptr + i) = *(this->aptr + j)
                *(this->aptr + j) = temporary; // here is where the errors appear
                                               // also, it doesn't appear anywhere else
                                               // e.g. on the line above it.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please, I would really appreciate if someone could tell me if I'm missing something here. I'm trying to do this in Xcode and I would try to "force run" it but I don't know how to do that nor do I know of a feature like that in Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a `;` at the end of:

```
*(this->aptr + i) = *(this->aptr + j)
```

(the line before the error line)

Answer (score 1):

A semicolon is missing here:

```
*(this->aptr + i) = *(this->aptr + j)
```